# How do I separate a string?

Tags: ruby

If I have a file containing data structured like this:

```
unknown|0   
Action|1  
Adventure|2  
Animation|3  
...
```

How do I separate the string in front of the "`|`" and the number after it so that I can create a hash like:

```
{"unknown"=> 0, "Action" => 1...}
```

Comment: I think you can just iterate over the file, line-by-line, and split each line with `.split('|')`. That will return `unknown` and `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOOO ugly but it works!

```
h=Hash[*s.chomp.split("\n").map{|i| i.split("|")}.flatten]
```

Answer (score 3):

`String#split` is your friend:

```
s = "unknown|0"
key, value = s.split("|")
hash = { key => value }
```

Or if you prefer to type less and obfuscate more:

```
Hash[*s.split("|")]
```

EDIT

Obviously this doesn't deal with reading lines from the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest to follow is something like:

```
hash = {}  
data.each_line do |line|
  split = line.split('|')
  hash[split[0]] = split[1]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the file **/tmp/foo**, you can parse the entire file into a hash in a single line like so:

```
Hash[*IO.readlines('/tmp/foo').map(&:chomp).collect { |l| l.split('|') }.flatten]
```

It's not really very readable, but it works.